# Hierarchical ssh connection with Putty, or maybe some other software?

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, putty, tunnel

There's this great app on Android called "Juice SSH". It has this wonderful feature where you can hierarchically connect to servers, which makes tunnelling super easy through many servers.

For example, you define a connection `ThisMachine -> A`. Let's call this connection/profile "Alpha". Then, you can define the connection Beta, which connects `ThisMachine -> B`. You can simply tell it to use Alpha for that connection, and seamlessly, it'll make the connection `ThisMachine -> A -> B`. Then you can define a connection Charlie as `ThisMachine -> C`, and then tell it "use Beta". Then it'll automatically connect with `ThisMachine -> A -> B -> C`. The chain can be as long as you want.

You can even establish tunnels or SOCKS proxies on ports using Alpha, Beta or Charlie, with any path you want!

What a beautiful feature! I tunnel through 5 servers with it without even having to think about it. Why create VPNs when ssh can do the job?!

Is there a way to do this with Putty, or any other similar software on Windows?

EDIT: There seems to be a misunderstanding from what I see in the comments. I know ssh tunnels. I know how to create them in putty **per connection** (and I use it for all kinds of applications, such as secure VNC), and it being per connection is the problem. What I'm looking for is automatic multi-level or hierarchical tunneling.

Comment: @Mokubai well, if I can call ssh in the terminal (as per the answer with `-J` flag), then why use `plink`? Does it offer anything in addition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>This is *possible* to implement with other SSH clients, just more tedious – e.g. with PuTTY (or its command-line counterpart `plink`) you have to manually start a connection to A, then to B, then to C (or the other way around? I didn't 100% understand.)</del>

In PuTTY, this *might* be possible by saving connection profiles through the GUI and loading them through plink.

- For example, configure PuTTY to connect to host A, and save it as "hostA".
- Then configure PuTTY to connect to host B and specify the following "Telnet or local proxy command" – then save the profile as "hostB":

  ```
  plink -nc %host %port -load hostA
  ```
- Configure PuTTY to connect to host C and specify the same proxy command, except make it load the "hostB" profile. Save *this* profile as "hostC"...

OpenSSH – which is also available for Windows – allows doing the same by configuring "ProxyCommand" for each server in ~/.ssh/config, so that `ssh C` wouldn't create a direct TCP connection but use a given command (which in this case happens to be a SSH-based TCP tunnel through B):

- Put this in ~/.ssh/config (same location in Windows too):

  ```
  Host thisHost
      ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p hostA

  Host hostA
      ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p hostB

  Host hostB
      ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p hostC
  ```
- Now running `ssh thisHost` will spawn three nested ProxyCommands.

However, OpenSSH has also recently added the "**ProxyJump**" option which automates both the command and even the chaining:

- The `-J` option alone acts as a shortcut for using `ssh -W` as the proxy command:

  ```
  ssh -J hostB hostA
  ```
- But it also directly accepts a comma-separated list of hosts:

  ```
  ssh -J hostA,hostB,hostC hostD
  ```
- The ~/.ssh/config setting looks pretty much the same:

  ```
  Host thismachine
      ProxyJump hostA,hostB,hostC
  ```

Comment: To answer your first paragraph. Yes. A, then to B, then from B to C, etc, is what I'm looking for. But as you said, it's tedious, and I'm hoping there's a way to automate it to be as elegant as Juice SSH.

Comment: The `-J` flag is what I was looking for. I just tested it. Not super elegant, but it'll do. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, hmm, I forgot that plink can also load profiles configured through PuTTY - so it's possible to configure the profile for host A to run `plink -nc %h:%p -load B...` as its proxy command, and so forth...

Comment: Anyway, I do think that `-J` and ProxyJump is _exactly_ what you were asking for, and it sounds to me like you have completely missed the part about configuring it via ~/.ssh/config. Do take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: The comma-separated list of hosts with `-J` is what I found out when I accepted your answer by doing some online research. The configuration in `~/.ssh/config` is something that I might look into if I ever need it. But for now, I'm happy with defining a path and ssh'ing into any machine with that. Thanks, again.